How do you initialize a ViewModel that uses the new required modifier on required properties?
In older C#, I would have a view model class like this:
public class MyViewModel
{
    [Required]
    public string FirstName { get; set; }

    public string MiddleName { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string LastName{ get; set; }
}

Then in my controller, I would do:
var model = new MyViewModel();
return View(model);

I know you might just not pass a view model into the view on GET, but imagine I need to to set other properties.
Now in newer C#, I'm doing this instead:
public class MyViewModel
{
    public required string FirstName { get; set; }

    public string MiddleName { get; set; }

    public required string LastName{ get; set; }
}

But now the compiler won't let me create new MyViewModel() anymore, because I have to set the required properties. I understand why, because that's how required works. But I don't want to set any initial values for those properties; because I want the user to fill them out on the form/View. They're "required" because I want the built-in validation that won't let them submit.
I can get around this by initializing them all to empty string; either in the view model itself or in the controller when I instantiate the class. But this seems almost like a hack, or at the least it leads to ugly code. Is there a proper/expected way to do this?

The annoying thing about required is that it's completely unnecessary: a good ol' fashioned parameterized constructor is far, far better - at the "cost" of having to actually write a ctor.

Anyway, in my case, I define a FoobarPageViewModel class (with a parameterised constructor) that's instantiated only within a Controller Action, which contains all of the one-way data that goes into a View; and a separate FoobarFormModel class, which contains only mutable properties for two-way data I'll be rendering for a <form> (and the PageViewModel exposes the FormModel via a Form property). Only snag is the asp-for="" binding expressions, but my workaround for that is to put all <form> elements into a Partial view file.

BTW, in your case, you're not using the required  modifier appropriately - required isn't appropriate for classes used with <form> model-binding because required absolutely requires it to be set, but remember that in a HTML <form> the user's browser can still omit any-any-every <input /> name/value pair, so you should stick to using [Required] instead, because that's what it's there for.

@Dai Could be a separate question, but if I don’t use required modifier, and declare the attributes as nullable, then it complains when I assign the posted model properties to my non-nullable entity properties, because it does consider ModelState.IsValid as proper null protection.

The required modifier is orthogonal to #nullable, though - you can have a required String? PropName { get; set; } and explicitly set it to null and that's a-okay. (What I do in my projects is (when appropriate) my form-models have a method that returns a new object with the same "shape" as the form-model, but with a ctor (called in ther form-model's method) that asserts all required (whether required-but-can-be-null and required-and-cannot-be-null and anything else) is satisfied. It's more tedium, but with the huge advantage that it's provably correct.

It sounds like what I really want is not nullable and also not required. This then forces me to set default values in the class to avoid the warnings.

If you are going to suppress messages then I recommend suppressing the warnings  using only explicit #pragma warning disable and always with a justification comment attached - whereas I recommend against setting defaults in initializers because I feel it obscures ASP.NET Core's model-binding process (which may-or-may-not overwrite your initializers and change those properties anyway)

Off the top of my head, two ways I could think of doing this would be the first option you already mentioned;
Simply initializing the properties with default values
public class MyViewModel
{
    public required string FirstName { get; set; } = string.Empty;

    public string MiddleName { get; set; } = string.Empty;

    public required string LastName { get; set; } = string.Empty;
}

// In the controller
var model = new MyViewModel();
return View(model);

OR
Use some form of centralized initialization
public class MyViewModel
{
    public required string FirstName { get; set; }

    public string MiddleName { get; set; }

    public required string LastName { get; set; }

    public static MyViewModel CreateEmpty()
    {
        return new MyViewModel
        {
            FirstName = string.Empty,
            MiddleName = string.Empty,
            LastName = string.Empty
        };
    }
}

Then in the controller, you can do this
var model = MyViewModel.CreateEmpty();
return View(model);


I downvoted this because it simply doesn't work: using a required modifier in a class type used as a type-parameter in ASP.NET Core will give you a compiler error because that type is not instantiable by ASP.NET Core's model-binder.
